# UnsatisfiableError with conda update conda

Tags: conda

I am getting an error when trying to update conda from the terminal using the command `conda update conda`. It is saying:

```
Solving environment: failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - conda
  - conda-canary::conda
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

with `conda --version` it printed out `conda 4.5.4` and `conda list` is working. Can anybody have any idea how to solve this problem? Looking into conda installation path `/home/samuel/anaconda3/conda-meta` I cannot find any file named pinned.

```
pathlib2-2.3.2-py36_0.json
path.py-11.0.1-py36_0.json
patsy-0.5.0-py36_0.json
pcre-8.42-h439df22_0.json
pep8-1.7.1-py36_0.json
pexpect-4.5.0-py36_0.json
pickleshare-0.7.4-py36h63277f8_0.json
pillow-5.1.0-py36h3deb7b8_0.json
pip-10.0.1-py36_0.json
pixman-0.34.0-hceecf20_3.json
pkginfo-1.4.2-py36_1.json
pluggy-0.6.0-py36hb689045_0.json
ply-3.11-py36_0.json
prompt_toolkit-1.0.15-py36h17d85b1_0.json
psutil-5.4.5-py36h14c3975_0.json
ptyprocess-0.5.2-py36h69acd42_0.json
py-1.5.3-py36_0.json
pycodestyle-2.4.0-py36_0.json
pycosat-0.6.3-py36h0a5515d_0.json
pycparser-2.18-py36hf9f622e_1.json
```

Comment: What are the contents of the file `path/to/anaconda/dir/conda-meta/pinned`?

Comment: The directory is filled with lots of .json files in it a little bit hard to put them in here

Comment: There should be one file called `pinned`, although it may not exist. If it does not exist please [edit] your question to mention that

Comment: Just edited the question I have no pinned file

Comment: Can you try writing `conda install defaults::conda`?

Comment: It didn't work giving the UnsatisfiableError again.

Comment: Can you post the contents of the `~/.condarc` file?

Comment: There is no file named .condarc in my home directory. I tried running `ls -a | grep conda` in the home directory has the following output `anaconda3
.bashrc-anaconda3.bak
.conda`

Comment: Do I have to uninstall and reinstall it @darthbith

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure what the problem is. That might fix it...

Comment: I managed to solve the problem by uninstalling conda virtual environment using this [link](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/) and installing it again( You can use this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-anaconda-python-distribution-on-ubuntu-16-04) to do so). Both `conda update conda` and `conda update spyder` are working after all.

Comment: This lmay be completely specific to my case, but somehow removing `stackless` from the `channels:` section of `~/.condarc` resolved this issue for me. I'm not really sure how channels fit into all this, but I'm leaving this for anyone else (this was particularly painful because reinstalling conda and removing pip packages had no effect)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone else stumbles across this issue I was able to work around this without having to reinstall anaconda by doing the following:

First remove `conda-canary` from your pinned packages:

```sh
$ conda config --system --remove pinned_packages conda-canary::conda
```

Then update conda as you would normally do:

```sh
$ conda update conda
```

From what I can tell so far this hasn't had any unintended consequences and should be easier than uninstalling and reinstalling anaconda.